# Is the equipartition theorem derivable from more basic principles

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Is the equipartition theorem really a theorem and derivable from more basic assumptions or is it just a hypothesis.  Some of the ways energy is partition is not to squared quantum numbers (e.g. vibration) although translation and rotation are

Comment: Yes, it can be derived from the canonical ensemble.

Comment: Why vibration is not squared?

Comment: And btw it holds only in classical SM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For which systems is the equipartition theorem valid?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3687/)

Comment: Knzhou -- could you point me to a reference where the equipartition theorem is derived from the canonical ensemble?   Thanks.

Comment: The best explanation of equipartition that I've found is in "Modern Physics"  Jeremy Bernstein et. al. Prentice Hall (2000) pp. 339 -342.  Each quadratic degree of freedom gives 1/2 kT to the energy.   The only trick is getting vibration which has a linear dependence on vibrational quantum number into a quadratic form -- they do this by splitting vibration into kinetic and potential forms - both of which are quadratic.  Then it's just a matter of integrating X^2 * exp (- X^2/kT) and dividing by the partition function.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the linked question. Note one asks for the conditions for the theorem to hold (and no derivation of the theorem or the conditions) the other asks for a derivation from basic principles. The closest thing to an answer to this question on stackexchange can actually be found here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20944/the-equipartition-theorem-in-momentum-space?rq=1.